# What slows Aggregate<IEnumerable<char>, StringBuilder> compared to my extension method?

Tags: c#, string, performance, lambda, aggregate

Some time ago I had a case where it was convinient to use `MyString.Skip(..).Take(..)` instead of `MyString.Substring(..)`. But `Skip` and `Take` return an `IEnumerable<char>` instead of a new `string`, so I wrote my own concat function:

```
    public static string Concat(this IEnumerable<char> char_sequence) {
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (var c in char_sequence)
        {
            sb.Append(c);
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }
```

Today I had to do the same thing but remembered to use `Aggregate` instead:

```
MyString.Skip(..).Take(..).Aggregate(new StringBuilder(), (current, next) => current.Append(next)).ToString()
```

Because the code was already there, I ran a quick performance test. `Aggregate` seems to be over 50% slower for large text files:

```
480KB .txt document, 1000 iterations (loading the document was not included in the test)

Function | Time (ms)
--------------------
Aggregate|    14,701
Concat   |     8,068
```

But why? According to [referencesource](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,82b209add5c21465), `Aggregate` uses this method:

```
    public static TAccumulate Aggregate<TSource, TAccumulate>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, TAccumulate seed, Func<TAccumulate, TSource, TAccumulate> func) {
        if (source == null) throw Error.ArgumentNull("source");
        if (func == null) throw Error.ArgumentNull("func");
        TAccumulate result = seed;
        foreach (TSource element in source) result = func(result, element);
        return result;
    }
```

Which, if you replace `TSource` with `char` and `TAccumulate` with `StringBuilder`, is basically the same code. Where does this difference in speed come from and is there a way to speed up `Aggregate`?

Just for completeness, I actually did more than these two benchmarks before I wrote the question (although I somehow forgot about `Substring` for some reason, so I had to run it again). Please remember that my question is not about what to use but rather why there's a difference between `Aggregate` and the custom `Concat`.

```
Function                | Time (ms)         (Additional Notes)
-----------------------------------------------------------
Aggregate               |    14070
Parallel().Aggregate    |    14016        (uses only one thread)
new String()            |     7784
String.Concat           |    13342
Concat Extension        |     7997
Substring               |      329
```

Comment: For fun, include a timing difference with `String.Substring`, which should be very substantial and give you some hint as to how enumerables and lambdas slow things down in this case.

Comment: why not just to use `string.Concat`?..

Comment: Post updated. I expected Substring to be the fastest but not more than 20 times faster. Concat ist pretty slow.

Comment: It's the difference between a native copy loop on bytes (`Substring`) and invoking a method dynamically at runtime (anything using delegates). All things considered the generic approaches are actually doing pretty well.

Comment: This blog post has some good information explaining the exact technical reasons why delegates have the overhead they do compared to explicit method invocations. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericgu/2004/03/19/speed-of-direct-calls-vs-interfaces-vs-delegates-vs-virtuals/